# Viewing more than 1000 rows in RStudio

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

In RStudio when you use the `View()` function, it only allows you to see up to 1000 rows. Is there any way to see more than that. I know it is possible to subset the viewing and see rows 1000-2000 for example, but I would want to be able to see 1-2000. The best I could find was a comment about a year ago saying that it wasn't possible at the time but they were planning on fixing this.

Here's an example (note: I'm guessing you will have to run this in RStudio).

```
rstudio <- (1:2000)
View(rstudio)
```

Comment: I can see 2000 rows in RStudio (v 0.97.248)

Comment: Thats weird because I'm using v. 0.97.449

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `View` command is specifically for the little helper window.   You can easily view the full value in the actual console window.  If you want the same layout, use cbind.

```
cbind(rstudio)
```

which in fact will even give you the same nice row-numbering setup

And if that's too cumbersome

```
pview <- function(x, rows=100) { 
  if (length(x) > rows)
    print(cbind(x))
  else 
    print(cbind(head(x, rows/2)))
    print(cbind(tail(x, rows/2)))
 }
 pview(rstudio, 1998)
```

*you will need to clean that up to get the row names to lineup*

Answer (score 3):

You can change this setting, for instance:
    options(max.print=5000)